# Excess elements in scalar initializer when adding to vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector which has the `uint8_t` type.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
```

I'm trying to emplace back data given in the callback function to this vector using this way,

```
    void callback(const uint8_t data[], size_t size)
    {
        vec.emplace_back(data, data + size);
    }
```

However, it fails to compile and I'm getting `excess elements in scalar initializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emplace_back` appends *single* element to the vector, and its arguments are actually arguments for its constructor. To append many elements at once, use [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/), like:
`vec.insert(vec.end(), data, data + size);`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, even the link you gave to insert does not define ```std::vector::insert(const_iterator, T*, size_t)```

Comment: But `data + size` is *not* of type `size_t`, it’s `T*` just like `data` itself. And then, any pointer is an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>::emplace_back` takes a single element's constructor's (or initializer in the case of an `int`) arguments. Because you have a vector of type `uint8_t` it should just be initialized with an integral value. Instead you are passing an `int*` which is what `const int data[]` really is, and a size. That's why it is saying that there are excess elements, because you are trying to initialize a single `int` with two different values.

Instead what it seems you are trying to do is to emplace the entire array with which `data` is just a pointer to the front of.

The most straightforward way to do so is just to use a `for` loop iterating through all of the elements inside of `data` by using the number of elements given by `size`

For Instance

```
void callback(const uint8_t data[], size_t size)
{
    //This Line Is Optional But Should Help Performance 
    vec.reserve(vec.size() + size);
    //

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        vec.emplace_back(data[i]);
    }
}
```